# Comparing Hash table values and creating an array of top N words

Tags: c++, sorting, hashtable

I've created a hash table of structs. Each struct has count. I'm curious how I can go through each key and separate chain and find the highest count and add it to an array.

```
struct wordItem
{
    std::string word;
    int count;
    wordItem* next;
};
```

This is what i have so far. My thought process is to to compare each item with every item. So go to initial key, then traverse down each chain. 
Suggestions welcome.

```
void HashTable::printTopN(int n) {

wordItem* arr[n];
wordItem* temp;
int i;
for (i=0;i<hashTableSize; i++){
    temp = hashTable[i];
    while (temp!=NULL){
        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++){
            if(arr[n]->count<temp->count&&arr[n+1]->count<temp->count){

                arr[n]=arr[n+1];
                arr[n] = temp;
            }
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }


}
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)

    std::cout<<arr[n]->word<<"--"<<arr[n]->count;
```

}
Also this is my addWord function for more background info.

```
void HashTable::addWord(std::string word) {
int hash_val = getHash(word);
wordItem* prev = NULL;
wordItem* entry = hashTable[hash_val];
while (entry != NULL)
{
    prev = entry;
    entry = entry->next;
}
    if (entry == NULL)
    {
        entry = new wordItem;
        entry->count = 1;
        entry->word = word;
        entry ->next = NULL;
        if (prev == NULL)
        {
            hashTable[hash_val]= entry;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->next = entry;
        }
}
    incrementCount(word);
    entry->word = word;

}
```

HPP fiie

```
struct wordItem
{
    std::string word;
    int count;
    wordItem* next;
};

const int STOPWORD_LIST_SIZE = 50;


class HashTable {

public:
    HashTable(int hashTableSize);
    ~HashTable();
    void getStopWords(char *ignoreWordFileName);
    bool isStopWord(std::string word);
    bool isInTable(std::string word);
    void incrementCount(std::string word);
    void addWord(std::string word);
    int getTotalNumberNonStopWords();
    void printTopN(int n);
    int getNumUniqueWords();
    int getNumCollisions();
    int getHash(std::string word);
private:


    wordItem* searchTable(std::string word);
    int numUniqueWords;
    int numCollisions;
    int hashTableSize;
    wordItem** hashTable;
    std::vector<std::string> vecIgnoreWords =
            std::vector<std::string>(STOPWORD_LIST_SIZE);

};
```

Comment: What does your `HashTable` class look like? Also, I would have expected that in your `for` loop in `printTopN()` i should start from `0` rather than `hashTableSize-1`.

Comment: That was when I was gonna read from the back the list. Ive updated it.

Comment: I see. Do you need the top `N` from the current chain or from the entire table?

Comment: I need it from the entire table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of `N` items. For each item in the table, go through the array and check if `current_array_item <= table_item <= next_array_item`. If yes, shift all items in the array that are `<= current_array_item` by one (erasing the smallest one from the array) and insert `table_item` in place of `current_array_item`.

Comment: Think i get what youre, saying. I tried implementing it up top. looks like im rewriting the same thing over in to each array index. suggestios?

Comment: Yes, first replace `arr[n]` with `arr[j]`. Iterate over the array and if you find a suitable position, you have to iterate over the array *again* (inside the `if` statement) up to the current item and shift by 1 (so `arr[0] = arr[1]`, `arr[1] = arr[2]) and so on.

Comment: Also, you might want to use `arr[j]->count <= temp->count && arr[j+1]->count <= temp->count` to check for items with equal counts. I have edited my answer accordingly.